# windeployqt.exe on Linux Distributions

Tags: linux, qt, dependencies

In windows you can run windeployqt.exe to approximate the library, qml, and plugin dependencies of a Qt application.

In Linux I can use ldd to determine library dependencies, but I have not found a way to establish which additional Qml files need to be present as well as which plugins I should include in my installer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There is the [linuxdeployqt](https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt) project on github, which can be helpful.

From looking at linuxdeployqt code it seems:

- finding the list of plugins is done by parsing the linked libraries
- qml files are parsed with qmlimportscanner. Here's the comment from code:

  > Scan qml files in qmldirs for import statements, deploy used imports from Qml2ImportsPath to ./qml